# Google Cloud AISE TensorFlow NVidia GPU Production - tensorflow doesn't see GPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gpu

I want to run my python script (tensorflow) on GPU, I have created on google cloud "AISE TensorFlow NVidia GPU Production", but tensorflow see only CPU, could you help me fix it?

GPU is visible by nvidia-smi:

```
tensorflow15-python3-cuda91-1-vm:/jet/prs/neurons$ nvidia-smi 
Thu Jan 31 19:45:14 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.51                 Driver Version: 396.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    27W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But from python tensorflow lavel it is unvisible.

```
>>>device_lib.list_local_devices()
2019-01-31 19:48:46.781083: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 17923278647472989696
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 16762846457299912213
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
>>>test.is_gpu_available()
False
>>>test.gpu_device_name()
# empty
```

Comment: How did you install tensorflow? pip install tensorflow or pip install tensorflow-gpu ?

Comment: Tensorflow has been installed on VM image..